# Partition by year and sub-partition by month mysql

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have a database with a date column having datatype as date.

The table is expected to have 10k rows each day. I want to create partition on the table on year range and then sub partitions on months of that particular year.

I have tried is,

```
ALTER TABLE nav_master
    PARTITION BY RANGE( YEAR(nav_date) )
    SUBPARTITION BY HASH( MONTH(nav_date) )
    SUBPARTITIONS 12 (
        PARTITION january VALUES LESS THAN (2),
        PARTITION february VALUES LESS THAN (3),
        PARTITION march VALUES LESS THAN (4),
        PARTITION april VALUES LESS THAN (5),
        PARTITION may VALUES LESS THAN (6),
        PARTITION june VALUES LESS THAN (7),
        PARTITION july VALUES LESS THAN (8),
        PARTITION august VALUES LESS THAN (9),
        PARTITION september VALUES LESS THAN (10),
        PARTITION october VALUES LESS THAN (11),
        PARTITION november VALUES LESS THAN (12),
        PARTITION december VALUES LESS THAN (13)
    );
```

I am able to execute the above query on empty table. But when I insert or when I execute the above query in same table with some data I get the below error.

```
#1526 - Table has no partition for value 2014
```

Not able to understand what the exact error is.

Also let me know if sub partitions help in better optimizing the tables or I should just go with partitions?

Comment: Duplicate of [this question at DBA.SE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/65665/83298)

Comment: This kind of `PARTITIONing` is usually not as efficient as a non-partitioned table with a suitable index.  Let's see the important `SELECTs` and discuss them.  As an example, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75492959/how-to-partition-a-table-by-year-and-then-subpartition-by-month-in-mysql-8 and my answer to it.

Answer (score 2):

Run this code on http://phpfiddle.org. you can also modify year range in the code.

```php
<?php
$sql = 'ALTER TABLE nav_master PARTITION BY RANGE(YEAR(nav_date))
SUBPARTITION BY HASH(MONTH(nav_date) ) (';
$startYear = 2019;
$endYear = 2022;
for ($y = $startYear; $y <= $endYear; $y++) {
    $yy = $y + 1;
    $sql .= " PARTITION p$y VALUES LESS THAN ($yy)
(
SUBPARTITION p" . $y . "_dec ,
SUBPARTITION p" . $y . "_jan ,
SUBPARTITION p" . $y . "_feb ,
SUBPARTITION p" . $y . "_mar ,
SUBPARTITION p" . $y . "_apr ,
SUBPARTITION p" . $y . "_may ,
SUBPARTITION p" . $y . "_jun ,
SUBPARTITION p" . $y . "_jul ,
SUBPARTITION p" . $y . "_aug ,
SUBPARTITION p" . $y . "_sep ,
SUBPARTITION p" . $y . "_oct ,
SUBPARTITION p" . $y . "_nov )";
    $sql .= ($y != $endYear) ? ',' : ')';
}
echo $sql;
?>
```

OR run manually below query.

```sql
ALTER TABLE nav_master PARTITION BY RANGE(YEAR(nav_date))
 SUBPARTITION BY HASH(MONTH(nav_date) )
  (   PARTITION p2016 VALUES LESS THAN (2017) (
            SUBPARTITION dec_2016,
            SUBPARTITION jan_2016,
            SUBPARTITION feb_2016,
            SUBPARTITION mar_2016,
            SUBPARTITION apr_2016,
            SUBPARTITION may_2016,
            SUBPARTITION jun_2016,
            SUBPARTITION jul_2016,
            SUBPARTITION aug_2016,
            SUBPARTITION sep_2016,
            SUBPARTITION oct_2016,
            SUBPARTITION nov_2016
        ),
        PARTITION p2017 VALUES LESS THAN (2018) (
            SUBPARTITION dec_2017,
            SUBPARTITION jan_2017,
            SUBPARTITION feb_2017,
            SUBPARTITION mar_2017,
            SUBPARTITION apr_2017,
            SUBPARTITION may_2017,
            SUBPARTITION jun_2017,
            SUBPARTITION jul_2017,
            SUBPARTITION aug_2017,
            SUBPARTITION sep_2017,
            SUBPARTITION oct_2017,
            SUBPARTITION nov_2017
        )
   );
```

Comment: I have added solutions after many year. still there is no proper solution I didn't found after google.

Answer (score 0):

You want all your data to be organized by year and then by month, then this may be more suitable:

```
    PARTITION BY HASH( YEAR(nav_date) )
        SUBPARTITION BY HASH( MONTH(nav_date) )
    ...
```

Comment: Gives me an error `#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'RANGE( MONTH(nav_date) ) SUBPARTITIONS 12 ( PARTITION january VALU' at line 3`

Comment: unfortunately there is a restriction on subpartitions "Subpartitions may use either HASH or KEY partitioning"

Comment: you you mean I cannot use sub partitions?

Comment: you definitely can use subpartitions but with the following restrictions  found at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-limitations.html

Answer (score 0):

```
        PARTITION january VALUES LESS THAN (2),
        PARTITION february VALUES LESS THAN (3),
        PARTITION march VALUES LESS THAN (4),
        PARTITION april VALUES LESS THAN (5),
        PARTITION may VALUES LESS THAN (6),
        PARTITION june VALUES LESS THAN (7),
        PARTITION july VALUES LESS THAN (8),
        PARTITION august VALUES LESS THAN (9),
        PARTITION september VALUES LESS THAN (10),
        PARTITION october VALUES LESS THAN (11),
        PARTITION november VALUES LESS THAN (12),
        PARTITION december VALUES LESS THAN (13)
```

This part compare the value with **YEAR(nav_date)**, hence the value '2014' does not fit any of conditions you declared.

Since you are not able to Subpartition by RANGE or LIST, you will not be able to get the result you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are utilizing 2 layers of the same functionality giving you no big advantage. I would prefer go with month (INTERVAL) based only partitioning for 1 level and try to find other key for sub-partition on level 2 like data type (transaction type for example, etc.).

Do not expect much improvement with 2 layers of INTERVAL based partitioning.

Answer (score 0):

By month and day of the month (assuming 31 days per month)

```php
<?php

$header = 'ALTER TABLE flights PARTITION BY RANGE(departure_date_month)
SUBPARTITION BY HASH(departure_date_day) (' . "\n";

$months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mai', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
$partitions = [];

foreach ($months as $key => $month) {
    $sql = '    PARTITION p_month_' . $month . ' VALUES LESS THAN (' . ($key + 2) . ') (' . "\n";
    $days = [];
    for ($i = 1; $i < 32; $i++) {
        $days[] = "\t" . 'SUBPARTITION p_month_' . $month . '_day_' . $i;
    }
    $sql .= implode(', ' . "\n", $days) . "\n";
    $partitions[] = $sql;
}

echo $header . implode('    ), ' . "\n", $partitions) . '    )' . "\n);\n";
```

```sql
ALTER TABLE flights PARTITION BY RANGE(departure_date_month)
SUBPARTITION BY HASH(departure_date_day) (
    PARTITION p_month_Jan VALUES LESS THAN (2) (
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_1, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_2, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_3, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_4, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_5, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_6, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_7, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_8, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_9, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_10, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_11, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_12, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_13, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_14, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_15, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_16, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_17, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_18, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_19, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_20, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_21, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_22, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_23, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_24, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_25, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_26, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_27, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_28, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_29, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_30, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jan_day_31
    ), 
    PARTITION p_month_Feb VALUES LESS THAN (3) (
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_1, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_2, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_3, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_4, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_5, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_6, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_7, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_8, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_9, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_10, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_11, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_12, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_13, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_14, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_15, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_16, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_17, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_18, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_19, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_20, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_21, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_22, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_23, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_24, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_25, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_26, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_27, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_28, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_29, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_30, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Feb_day_31
    ), 
    PARTITION p_month_Mar VALUES LESS THAN (4) (
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_1, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_2, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_3, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_4, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_5, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_6, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_7, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_8, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_9, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_10, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_11, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_12, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_13, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_14, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_15, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_16, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_17, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_18, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_19, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_20, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_21, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_22, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_23, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_24, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_25, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_26, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_27, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_28, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_29, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_30, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mar_day_31
    ), 
    PARTITION p_month_Apr VALUES LESS THAN (5) (
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_1, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_2, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_3, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_4, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_5, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_6, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_7, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_8, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_9, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_10, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_11, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_12, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_13, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_14, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_15, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_16, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_17, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_18, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_19, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_20, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_21, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_22, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_23, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_24, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_25, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_26, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_27, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_28, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_29, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_30, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Apr_day_31
    ), 
    PARTITION p_month_Mai VALUES LESS THAN (6) (
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_1, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_2, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_3, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_4, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_5, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_6, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_7, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_8, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_9, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_10, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_11, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_12, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_13, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_14, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_15, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_16, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_17, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_18, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_19, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_20, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_21, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_22, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_23, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_24, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_25, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_26, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_27, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_28, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_29, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_30, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Mai_day_31
    ), 
    PARTITION p_month_Jun VALUES LESS THAN (7) (
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_1, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_2, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_3, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_4, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_5, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_6, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_7, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_8, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_9, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_10, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_11, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_12, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_13, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_14, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_15, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_16, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_17, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_18, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_19, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_20, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_21, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_22, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_23, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_24, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_25, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_26, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_27, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_28, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_29, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_30, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jun_day_31
    ), 
    PARTITION p_month_Jul VALUES LESS THAN (8) (
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_1, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_2, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_3, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_4, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_5, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_6, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_7, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_8, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_9, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_10, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_11, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_12, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_13, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_14, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_15, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_16, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_17, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_18, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_19, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_20, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_21, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_22, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_23, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_24, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_25, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_26, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_27, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_28, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_29, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_30, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Jul_day_31
    ), 
    PARTITION p_month_Aug VALUES LESS THAN (9) (
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_1, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_2, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_3, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_4, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_5, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_6, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_7, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_8, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_9, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_10, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_11, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_12, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_13, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_14, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_15, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_16, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_17, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_18, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_19, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_20, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_21, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_22, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_23, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_24, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_25, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_26, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_27, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_28, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_29, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_30, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Aug_day_31
    ), 
    PARTITION p_month_Sep VALUES LESS THAN (10) (
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_1, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_2, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_3, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_4, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_5, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_6, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_7, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_8, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_9, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_10, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_11, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_12, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_13, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_14, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_15, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_16, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_17, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_18, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_19, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_20, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_21, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_22, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_23, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_24, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_25, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_26, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_27, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_28, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_29, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_30, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Sep_day_31
    ), 
    PARTITION p_month_Oct VALUES LESS THAN (11) (
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_1, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_2, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_3, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_4, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_5, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_6, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_7, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_8, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_9, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_10, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_11, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_12, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_13, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_14, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_15, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_16, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_17, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_18, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_19, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_20, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_21, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_22, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_23, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_24, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_25, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_26, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_27, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_28, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_29, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_30, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Oct_day_31
    ), 
    PARTITION p_month_Nov VALUES LESS THAN (12) (
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_1, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_2, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_3, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_4, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_5, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_6, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_7, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_8, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_9, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_10, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_11, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_12, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_13, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_14, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_15, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_16, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_17, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_18, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_19, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_20, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_21, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_22, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_23, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_24, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_25, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_26, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_27, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_28, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_29, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_30, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Nov_day_31
    ), 
    PARTITION p_month_Dec VALUES LESS THAN (13) (
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_1, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_2, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_3, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_4, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_5, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_6, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_7, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_8, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_9, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_10, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_11, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_12, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_13, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_14, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_15, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_16, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_17, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_18, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_19, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_20, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_21, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_22, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_23, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_24, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_25, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_26, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_27, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_28, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_29, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_30, 
    SUBPARTITION p_month_Dec_day_31
    )
);
```